# How to call one action after other action is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have several fetch actions with thunk, for example:

```
function addARequest( return (dispatch) => { return fetch(blablabla).then(blablabla); }; )
function addBRequest( return (dispatch) => { return fetch(blablabla).then(blablabla); }; )
function addCRequest( return (dispatch) => { return fetch(blablabla).then(blablabla); }; )
```

and I have a requirement to call a action after each of them above was called.
But I don't want to add a dispatch in every action...like

```
function addARequest( return (dispatch) => {
     dispatch(aMustCalledActionAfterEveryOtherAction); 
     return fetch(blablabla).then(blablabla); }; 
)
```

I want it to run like an AOP or something.
Could anyone help me...?

Comment: Why can't you call dispatch? Are you wanting to call the action after it's fetched data?

Comment: because I don't want to call it everywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Redux middleware that will "listen" on all your actions:

http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Comment: thanks. but middleware triggers after every action, but I just want it to trigger after some of the actions...how to deal with that?

Comment: You would then have to use dispatch everywhere that you want to trigger the action.